# Exponential Generating Function for cooking recipe

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, generating-functions

Let $r_0 := 1$, and for $n \geq 1$ let $r_n$ be the number of ways to do the following:

(i) divide $n$ into an even number of recipes,

(ii) bookmark one recipe from each group, AND

(iii) choose half of the bookmarked recipes and THEN decide the order in which we will cook them.

Let $R(x)$ be the exponential generating function (EGF) of $r_n$, $n \geq 0$. Find a closed form formula for $R(x)$.

Here is my work: Let $k = 2m$ be a fixed integer. Then the number of ways to split the $n$ recipes into $k$ groups is the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ of $A(x)^k$ where $A(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 - \frac{x}{1-x}$. Thus the EGF of doing (i) and then (ii) is, after we define $b_n := n$, $G(x) = B(A(x)) := \displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_{2m}\frac{(A(x)^{2m}}{(2m)!} = \displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty 2m \frac{(A(x)^{2m}}{(2m)!} = A(x) \sin A(x)$. For the task (iii), the EGF is $C(x) := \displaystyle\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \binom{2m}{m}m! \frac{x^{2m}}{(2m)!} = e^{x^2} - 1$. Thus, the formula should be $C(B(A(x))) = e^{(A(x)sinA(x))^2} - 1$.

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Comment: I did not get the first step... could you make a cleaner layout with a sort of \enumerate? How do you "divide" you $n$?

Comment: Notice that $C(x)$ simplifies considerably, to $\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{2 m}}{m!} = \exp(x^2) - 1$.

Comment: Just to clarify - there are numerous ways of doing (i), (ii), (iii) that will result in the exact same ordered list of recipes to be cooked. Do each of these ways contribute separately to $r_n$, even though the resulting list is the same? For example, if you have 4 recipes $a,b,c,d$, you could have groups $\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}$. pick $a,d$ in that order. Or you could have groups $\{a,c\},\{b,d\}$ and still pick $a,d$ in that order. Does that count as one way, or two?